# R function to find the end value of consecutive values in a boolean vector

Tags: r, boolean

I am trying to find the last value of a set of consecutive  TRUEs in a boolean vector (is_reaching) in my dataframe which I extracted after a set of conditions as below:

transport_phase = last(rle(is_reaching)$lengths, rle(is_reaching)$lengths > 40, rle(is_reaching)$values==TRUE),
transport_phase_end = cumsum(rle(is_reaching)$lengths)[transport_phase]

The above code for transport_phase gives me the correct numeric vector for the last length of consecutive TRUEs in each of my grouped variables, but when I try to find the end value of this run of TRUEs, using transport_phase_end, it just gives me the length of the vector which is the same as the transport_phase rather than the absolute value of the TRUE in this run.

I've tried other similar options from ideas on this site, but none have worked? I'm using dplyr package.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: So @ronak shah looking at the following simple example: `data.frame(c(1:20),c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE))`                                                                
I would get 3 for the last length of consecutive values more than or equal to 3, but when I try to find the value of the last FALSE, I get 3 instead of 20.                                           Expected output would be transport_phase = 3 and transport_phase_end = 20

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this -

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:20),b = c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE))
tmp <- rle(df$b)
i <- max(which(tmp$lengths >= 3))
transport_phase_end <- max(cumsum(tmp$lengths[1:i]))
transport_phase_end
#[1] 20
transport_phase <- tmp$lengths[i]
transport_phase
#[1] 3
```